# How to set select as null or nothing when join from two tables?

Tags: sql-server

This is my first table1:

```
ID | Name1 | Name2 | Name3
---+-------+-------+------
1  |  aaa  |  bbb  |  ccc
2  |  aab  |  bbc  |  cca
3  |  abb  |  bcc  |  caa
```

And this is my another table2:

```
t1ID | NameT1
-----+-------
1    |  eee
1    |  fff
1    |  ggg
2    |  hhh
3    |  iii
3    |  jjj
```

I want to join both tables like this

```
ID | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | NameT1
---+-------+-------+-------+--------
1  |  aaa  |  bbb  |  ccc  |  eee
1  |       |       |       |  fff
1  |       |       |       |  ggg
2  |  aab  |  bbc  |  cca  |  hhh
3  |  abb  |  bcc  |  caa  |  iii
3  |       |       |       |  jjj
```

I've try using `INNER JOIN` and `UNION ALL` but it's give me this result

```
ID | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | NameT1
---+-------+-------+-------+--------
1  |  aaa  |  bbb  |  ccc  |  eee
1  |  aaa  |  bbb  |  ccc  |  fff
1  |  aaa  |  bbb  |  ccc  |  ggg
2  |  aab  |  bbc  |  cca  |  hhh
3  |  abb  |  bcc  |  caa  |  iii
3  |  abb  |  bcc  |  caa  |  jjj
```

So, Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Table in SQL Server are Set and Set don't preserve order. How can get express expected result as Set? It's still achievable by window function, but it doesn't make sense to group data by emptying some cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.[ID] ORDER BY T1.[ID]),
      ID = T1.[ID],
      T1.Name1,
      T1.Name2,
      T1.Name3,
      T2.NameT1
      FROM T1
        INNER JOIN T2
            ON T1.ID = T2.t1ID
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Name1 = CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Name1 END,
  Name2 = CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Name2 END,
  Name3 = CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Name3 END,
  NameT1
  FROM CTE
```

Please find the SQL Fiddle Here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/305ec/4

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. :)

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS**: You can achieve this result by using `CTE` and window function as below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA(ID INT, Name1 VARCHAR(50), Name2 VARCHAR(50), Name3 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #tableA VALUES
(1,'aaa','bbb','ccc'),
(2,'aab','bbc','cca'),
(3,'abb','bcc','caa')

CREATE TABLE #tableB(t1ID INT, NameT1 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #tableB VALUES
(1,'eee'),
(1,'fff'),
(1,'ggg'),
(2,'hhh'),
(3,'iii'),
(3,'jjj')

;WITH tabB AS (
    SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t1ID ORDER BY NameT1) rnk
    FROM #tableB B),

    tabA AS (
    SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name1) rnk
    FROM #tableA A)

SELECT B.t1ID, 
    ISNULL(A.Name1, '') AS Name1, 
    ISNULL(A.Name2, '') AS Name2, 
    ISNULL(A.Name3, '') AS Name3, 
    B.NameT1
FROM tabB B
LEFT JOIN tabA A ON A.rnk = B.rnk AND A.ID = B.t1ID
ORDER BY B.t1ID
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
t1ID    Name1   Name2   Name3   NameT1
1       aaa     bbb     ccc     eee
1                               fff
1                               ggg
2       aab     bbc     cca     hhh
3       abb     bcc     caa     iii
3                               jjj
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, this is also working for me :)